# jQuery fires twice for two nested elements with the same class name

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom-events

I have this button. I just noticed, if I have the same class name on two nested elements, the `click` listener will fire twice. When I click, how can I fix this?

```js
$('body').on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if ($(e.target).hasClass('remove')) {
    console.log('test'); //executed twice here
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn remove "><i class="fas fa-trash remove">Remove icon</i></button>
```

Comment: Its happening because you have set on click event on .remove class and the button has 2 elements with that class. One is the button itself and the other is the <i> tag. You need to use e.stopPropagation() to stop the event propagation from i to button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prevent propagation because you have parent/child with same class, so use `e.stopPropagation()`

```js
$('body').on('click', '.remove', e => {
  e.stopPropagation()
  $(e.currentTarget).hasClass('remove') ? console.log('test') : ''
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn remove"><i class="fas fa-trash remove">remove</i></button>
```

---

And here is JS pure solution

```js
document.addEventListener('click', e => e.target.classList.contains('remove') ? console.log('test') : '')
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button type="button" class="btn remove"><i class="fas fa-trash remove">remove</i></button>
```

**Note:** because you have `button`with a `type='button'`, there is no need to use `e.preventDefault()`